# Necessary and sufficient conditions for finite probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

While I'm solving the problem to find necessary and sufficient conditions for
$(\max_{m \leq n} Y_m)/n \rightarrow 0 \mbox{ almost surely}$, when $Y_1,Y_2,...$ are i.i.d random variables.

I need to show that
$$\sum P(Y_n > \epsilon n) < \infty \Leftrightarrow \sum P(Y_n^+ > \epsilon n) < \infty $$

But I thought since $Y_n^+ > Y_n$, $P(Y_n >\epsilon n) \leq P(Y^+_n > \epsilon n)$

Anyone could explain why
$$\sum P(Y_n > \epsilon n) < \infty \Leftrightarrow \sum P(Y_n^+ > \epsilon n) < \infty $$
above relation is correct?

Comment: can I please clarify the notation - do you mind defining $Y_n^+$? Is $Y_n^+ = max(0,Y_n)?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Y_N^+$ is defined to be $\max(0,Y_n)$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(Y_n > \epsilon n) 
&= \mathbb P((Y_n > \epsilon n) \wedge (Y_n>0))\\
&= \mathbb P(\max(0,Y_n) > \epsilon n)\\
&= \mathbb P(Y_n^+ > \epsilon n)\\
\sum\limits_n \mathbb P(Y_n > \epsilon n)  &= \sum\limits_n\mathbb P(Y_n^+ > \epsilon n)\\
\sum\limits_n \mathbb P(Y_n > \epsilon n) < \infty &\Leftrightarrow \sum\limits_n\mathbb P(Y_n^+ > \epsilon n) < \infty
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes I just forgot to define $Y_n^+$. Your definition is correct. I cannot understand first equation. What is the mean of $(Y_n>\epsilon n) \wedge (Y_n >0)$ , I know $\wedge$ means min, but $(Y_n>\epsilon n) $ isn't a real number right??

Comment: Sorry, if the answer wasn't that clear. $\wedge$ is the [logical conjunction][1]. So if $Y_n > \epsilon n$, then $Y_n > 0$ as $\epsilon n$ is positive. Therefore $\mathbb P [Y_n > \epsilon_n\text{ and }Y_n >0] = \mathbb P [Y_n > \epsilon_n]$ 


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction